# passing variale to javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

Faced a problem with passing a variable into javascript callback function. Can't understand, why it doesn't work.

Here is the code. I pass variable 'i' through many functions. 'function1' is just an example, there is a big piece of code.

also the code in callback, 'var tmpl' is just an example, don't pay attention to that. The problem is why i can't pass 'i' variable.

```
function function1() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       RequestData(i);
   }
}
function RequestData(i, callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', '/getitemID='+i, true);

    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // (3)
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
             alert(xhr.responseText);
             callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
        xhr.close();
    }
}

RequestData(i, function (json) {
    alert('here!');

    var tmpl = [
        '<div id="content"><div id="bodyContent">',
        '<button onclick="RequestData("+i+")">Load Data!</button></div>',
        '<div>#here!</div>'
    ].join('');

    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    alert(body);

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var html = tmpl.replace('#here!', json[i].itemid); 
        body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html); 
    }
});
```

if i try to calling callback like this: `function RequestData(i, callback) {`- i get 'unresolved type or variable 'i'' error, and callback doesn't work. else if i do not pass 'i' in callback - i do not get this error, but looks like callback doesn't work too, because this code for callback don't work `RequestData(function (json) { alert('here!');}` - i don't receive a message 'here', but no errors. in both situations callback call is: `callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));`

Comment: looks like your are being recursive.

Comment: When you call `RequestData()` from the `for` loop at the top, you don't pass a `callback` argument.

Comment: Why are you calling `RequestData` from inside `RequestData`?

Comment: @Barmar it was indent issue, he didn't call RequestData from RequestData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `i` is undefined because you are calling `RequestData(i, function())`, while `i` is not defined.

You only call RequestData from `function1()` but that method is never executed and never has a callback specified.

To make it work, remove the  `RequestData(i)` call from  `function1()`. Then put the method call  `RequestData(i, function (json) {` inside the the for loop. Finally call `function1()` and you will get your result. (not with clean code though).

```
function function1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        RequestData(i, function (json) {
            alert('here!');

            var tmpl = [
                '<div id="content"><div id="bodyContent">',
                '<button onclick="RequestData("+i+")">Load Data!</button></div>',
                '<div>#here!</div>'
            ].join('');

            var body = document.querySelector('body');
            alert(body);

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                var html = tmpl.replace('#here!', json[i].itemid);
                body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
            }
        });
    }
}
function RequestData(i, callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', '/getitemID='+i, true);

    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // (3)
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
        //xhr.close(); // this is not an existing function
    }
}

// run the for loop by calling this method
function1();
```

Comment: oh and xhr.close() is not a function.